# Probability of sampling the same values multiple times from two non-independent sets

Tags: probability, independence

There are two sets of integers of size $|K|=4$, with the entries of the second set $j_k$ dependent on the entries in the first set $i_k$.

- $n \in N,\ n \geq 2$
- $K = \{ 0, \dots, 3 \}$
- $i_k \in \{0, \dots, n-2\}\ \forall\ k \in K$
- $j_k \in \{i_k + 1, \dots, n-1\}\ \forall\ k \in K$

Notice that it could happen that $i_0$ < $j_0$, $i_1 < j_1$, but $i_1 > j_0$.

Let's say we sample $4$ values for $i_k$ ($i_0, i_1, i_2, i_3$) and $4$ values for $j_k$ ($j_0, j_1, j_2, j_3$) at random, with uniform distribution over the domain of $i_k$ and $j_k$.

What is the probability that both all the entries in $i_k$ are equal and all the entries in $j_k$ are equal as well?
More precisely: what is $P(i_0 = i_1 = i_2 = i_3\ \wedge\ j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3)$?

Note: this is not a homework or a job interview question, it's merely a curiosity of mine that came up while working on a genetic algorithm project.

---

Here's what I've tried so far.

The probability that all $i_k$s are equal to a specific number $m$ should be:

$P(i_0 = i_1 = i_2 = i_3 = m) = \frac{1}{(n-1)^4}$

The probability that all $i_k$s are equal in general should be:

$P(i_0 = i_1 = i_2 = i_3) = \frac{1}{(n-1)^4} \cdot (n-1) = \frac{1}{(n-1)^3}$

I'm not sure how to compute the probabilities of $j_k$, since they are dependent on $i_k$: the following paragraph might contain errors.

Let $i^{(m)}$ be a fixed value for all $i_k$s.
The probability that all $j_k$s are equal to a specific number $q > m$ should be:

$P(j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3 = q) = \frac{1}{(n-1 - i^{(m)})^4}$

If we keep $i_m$ fixed and consider all the possible $q$s, we should obtain the following probability:

$P(j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3) = \frac{1}{(n-1 - i^{(m)})^3}$

I could proceed by enumerating cases for $i^{(m)}$:

$(i^{(m)} = 0) \Rightarrow\ P(j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3 = 1) = \frac{1}{(n-1)^4}$

$(i^{(m)} = 1) \Rightarrow\ P(j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3 = 2) = \frac{1}{(n-2)^4}$

$\dots$

$(i^{(m)} = n-2) \Rightarrow\ P(j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3 = n-1) = 1$

We should be able to rewrite this more concisely as:

$P(j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3 = i^{(m)}) = \frac{1}{((n-1)!)^4}$

And we could conclude with:

$P(i_0 = i_1 = i_2 = i_3\ \wedge\ j_0 = j_1 = j_2 = j_3) = \frac{1}{(n-1)^3} \cdot \frac{1}{((n-1)!)^4} = \frac{1}{(n-1)^7 \cdot ((n-2)!)^4}$

Can someone please check my calculations and correct me where I did mistakes? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but should add probabilities of different events that are disjoint.
$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-2} P[i_0=i_1=i_2=i_3=m]\times P[j_0=j_1=j_2=j_3|i_0=i_1=i_2=i_3=m]$$
$$=\sum_{m=0}^{n-2} \frac{1}{(n-1)^4}\times \frac{1}{(n-1-m)^3}$$
For $n=2, ..., 10$, the sum is:
1.
0.0703125
0.0143461
0.00460024
0.00189706
0.000918435
0.000496963
0.000291787
0.00018237